# how to set plugin position in wordpress divi themes (different result from visual builder)

Tags: wordpress

i've created a sample plugin:

```
<?php
/**
* Plugin Name: Coba coba
* Plugin URI: -
* Description: Cobacoba
* Version: 1.0
* Author: Anonymous
* Author URI: 
*/

function cobaeuy(){
    echo "<h1>Test Show Content</h1>";
}

add_shortcode('coba','cobaeuy');
?>
```

i wanted to add this plugin to my divi themes, 
please take a look at : [visual builder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MuhWf.jpg)

this plugin is set under "first section" but the result is on the top.
here :
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7nd84.jpg)

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever working with shortcodes, you must always return the output and not echo/print it from within the shortcode function.

Reason: All shortcodes inside post content are rendered before the content is printed to the browser. So, if you echo the shortcode output inside the shortcode, that means you sent it to the browser before the post content. When you return the output, it is inserted into the post content.

Correct code:

```
<?php
/**
* Plugin Name: Coba coba
* Plugin URI: -
* Description: Cobacoba
* Version: 1.0
* Author: Anonymous
* Author URI: 
*/

function cobaeuy(){
    return "<h1>Test Show Content</h1>";
}

add_shortcode('coba','cobaeuy');
?>
```